# MVC4 Model relationships and views error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Models

```
public class Adress {
public int Id { get; set; }
...
public virtual List<Pren> Pren { get; set; } // Subscription(s)
}

public class Pren {
public int Id { get; set; }
public int Adressid { get; set; }
public int Betalnr { get; set; } // payer id
...
public virtual Betalare Betalare { get; set; } // Payer
}

public class Betalare {
[Display(Name = "Nr")]
public int Id { get; set; }
...
}
```

Adress Edit view

```
@foreach (var pren in Model.Pren) {
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.ActionLink(pren.id.ToString(), "Edit", "Pren", new { id = pren.id }, null)
    </td>
    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => pren.Tidningid)</td>
    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => pren.Nfg)</td>
    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => pren.Priskod)</td>
    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => pren.Nasta_priskod)</td>
    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => pren.Saldo)</td>
</tr>
}
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id = 0)
    {
        Adress adress = db.Adresser.Find(id);
        if (adress == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(adress);
    }
```

When I go to **Adress/Edit/2** I get this error; all the Prens (subscriptions) have no Betalare (payer) so Pren.Betalnr = 0 if that helps.

> Invalid column name 'Betalare_Id'.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid column name 'Betalare_Id'.
>
> Line 90: @foreach (var pren in Model.Pren)

Invalid colum name, should I rename Betalare.Id to something else in my class and SQL db?

Edit: added controller code. My database have the field Id in table Betalare

Comment: Could you post the Edit action from your controller? Do the column exist in the database table?

Comment: MVC automatically adds '_' for Sub Level Model properties i.e pen.Betlare.Id

Comment: @scheien updated! And my database have the field Id in table Betalare

Comment: how is the Betalare related to the Pren? Its only related one way, might be the problem. I guess your view takes Betalare as Model?

Comment: Sounds like an entity mapping error - you should have a column called `Betalare_Id` in the `Pren` table as this will create the relationship between `Betalare->Pren`